# .net: debugger highlighting line of code not actually being executed

Tags: c#

Copy and paste the following into a new console application in VS. Add references to System.Web and System.Web.Services (I know console apps don't need these assemblies, I'm just showing you a snippet of code that does not work in my web application).

Although both conditions in the if statement are false, it's turning out to be true. Anyone know the reason why? (Visual Studio 2008 9.0.30729.1) .NET 3.5 SP1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = "qweqweqw";
            string y =
                "{\"textMedia\":[-1,-1,-1,-1,-1],\"textOperand\":[1,1,1,1,1],\"textString\":[\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\"],\"dateSite\":[-11],\"dateOperand\":[],\"dateString\":[],\"status\":[-11,0,0],\"media\":[-11,0,0],\"subItem\":true,\"context\":false,\"branchSearch\":false,\"profileIDs\":[2,5,18],\"profileViewIDs\":[48,58,38],\"currentSelectedBranch\":0}";

            SaveSearch(x, y);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static object SaveSearch(string name, string encodedSearch)
        {
            object response = new { };

            string x = name;
            string y = encodedSearch;

            // Why does this if statement throw an exception if both equal false?
            if (x.Trim().Equals(string.Empty) || y.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
                throw new AjaxErrorException("Save Search", "Something went wrong", "JSFunction");


            try
            {
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        error = false,
                        name = name,
                        userID = 123,
                        date = DateTime.Now
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String e;

                if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
                    e = ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace;
                else
                    e = "error error aliens approaching";

                throw new AjaxErrorException("Save Search", e, "");
            }

            return response;
        }

        public class AjaxErrorException : System.Exception
        {
            public AjaxErrorException(string title, string details, string function)
                : base(title)
            { }
            string _stackTrace;
            public override string StackTrace
            {
                get
                {
                    return _stackTrace;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Step through a debugger to see what is actually happening.

Comment: Why would I post it if i didnt?

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException or AjaxErrorException?

Comment: I just took that exact code, removed the WebMethod and the reference to HttpContext and ran it as a Console App. It doesn't throw an exception for me

Comment: I'm getting an AjaxErrorException. I have trimmed the strings and used IsNullOrEmpty() and the if statement still fails.

Comment: @pdr same for me! @Sir Psycho, this is not the code you are running or you're debugging against something else.

Comment: Does this actually throw an AjaxErrorException or another Exception? What are example values for name and encodedSearch that throw the exception? Sorry, not going to spin up an application, please just state: Precisely, What is happening under which conditions? What should happen instead?

Comment: I tried this in Visual Studio 2008, and I was unable to reproduce the error. I tried it in both debug and release both within the IDE and at the command prompt.

Comment: I pasted the 'if' statement by sitself into a console app and assigned x and y values. It behaved properly. When you run it in the debugger, what are the values for x and y that you see when your exception gets thrown?

Comment: @Jeff, if you debug, you will see that debugger actually step into the if block and over the throw although nothing was thrown, which make it interesting. I thought was a valid and interesting problem, I dont know why people are voting it down. I'm giving it a +1

Comment: Can't say I understand the code block surrounding the return nor the exception handler (with no possible chance of exception).  Also why is the StackTrace overridden to return an uninitalized string?

Comment: @Fadrian That's not what happened to me. Stepped over the if as-intended.

Comment: When I stepped through it, it went straight from the if to the return. All the values looked correct, and it behaved correctly.

Comment: @Jeff - Perhaps different version of VS works differently. Hopefully yours is later version than mine and the problem has been addressed :)

Comment: Just a quick note for people who guess that the string is null, look at the code provided. He calls the method with X and Y variable initialized with some string and passed into the method as parameter so the strings are definitely not null in the example above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually check and although the debugger step into the statement following the if (throw statement), it is not actually throw the exception. I suspect it is the inconsistency between IDE, IL generated and Debugger particularly  for throw statement. If you try other type of statement, you dont actually see the problem. It seems to related to this post too
[If statement weirdness in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605840/a-fundamental-problem-in-net-runtime-if-statement-weirdness)

I inserted the assert statement inside the if block like below to ensure there was no assertion triggered.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
```

Comment: @Psycho -Welcome. It is actually an interesting find and I was intrigued by it as well

Answer (score 1):

So I tried pasting this exact code into a new console application in vs2008 and adding the necessary references.  Here's what it did for me:

Running the application did not seem to throw any exception.  *However*, when I ran it in the debugger and stepped over line 30 (the line with the if), the debugger highlighted the net line (with the throw) in yellow.  I was able to keep stepping over code with no actual exception being thrown.  If I set a breakpoint on line 31 (the throw line) it never gets hit.

I think the debugger UI is simply off.  It does not appear to actually be executing that code.  I don't know what would cause that, but it does not seem to be anything to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

null is not the same as Empty.  So `null.Equals(string.Empty)` returns false.  But `null.Trim()` throws a null reference exception, and so you need to test for null in this code first.  `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, as suggested by @Otavio, is the correct way to do this.  Don't forget to trim the string after checking that, since you're obviously also worried about whitespace-only strings.

I know it doesn't help you right now, but .Net 4 will have a built-in method that does the trim, null check, and empty check all in the same method.

---

This should do what you need:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) || string.IsNullOrEmtpy(y) || x.Trim().Length == 0 || y.Trim().Length == 0)
```

Comment: @Sir Psycho - you still have to trim the string _if_ it passes the null check.

Comment: I trim() the strings and used IsNullOrEmpty() and this still does not work!

Comment: In the posted code, wouldn't x.Trim() throw a NullReferenceException if it was indeed null?

Comment: In his code, not mine.  Mine will short circuit if it's null and never check that.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this:

```
    string x = "   text   \t\t\n";
    string y = "not empty";

    if (x.Trim().Equals(string.Empty) || y.Trim().Equals(string.Empty))
        Console.WriteLine("TRUE");
```

And it didn't print 'TRUE' as expected.  There must be some other bug or perhaps in your actual code you have a semicolon after the 'if' statement?

Edit: With the exception throw instead of a writeline it doesn't throw either.  Are you sure this is the code that is throwing?

Comment: I'm confused. Why would you expect this to print TRUE? I'd expect the opposite.

Comment: The wording is mussed up, read it as follows: "And it didn't print 'TRUE'; as should be expected." Everything before the semicolon is what is expected in this case. Damn the internet.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the problem. First, delete the contents of the obj and bin directories in your project. Then reboot your computer.

If that doesn't fix the problem, then you may need to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: And why was this downvoted? It was a good-faith answer with a fairly good chance of success.

Comment: That does not fix anything, You can paste this code into a new console app (as i've stated already) and you'll get the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your one/both string variables are probably null, not empty.

**EDIT**
Why did you guys vote it down? 
I was guessing his statement throws NullReferenceException.

Anyway, maybe my answer wasn't clear enough :(

Comment: If that were the case, the Trim() would have thrown.

Comment: If they were null you would get a null reference exception.

Comment: @chrissr, @Otavio - You are right, but I was guessing he has null reference exception. He said "it's turning out to be true" so he thinks this it true as he is expecting to throw his AjaxErrorException but it doesn't work.